# Prebid server handling of 204 response from bidder

Tags: prebid

I am looking to capture a case when the `prebid` server receives no bid responses from a bidder. As per the openRTB spec, the bidders can respond back with a `204` or set the nbr attribute and http 200. How does the `prebid` server handle each of these cases? Does it forward the response directly as is ?

I randomly got a case where the `prebid` server seems to be sending back `http 200` to the client, so I am not sure how to parse the case with no bid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe prebid-server simply returns an empty bid response back to Prebid client side, then Prebid client side will filter out empty responses in that auction. If you are looking to handle this programmatically on your page I would recommend using the [public API from Prebid] (http://prebid.org/dev-docs/publisher-api-reference.html#module_pbjs.getBidResponses), specifically `getBidResponses`. Also, there is really no action you **need** to do as Prebid handles the no bid response on it's own.